# How to check if link (a) submit button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript

How do I check  with PHP if this code has been clicked so I can use it in an if statement?

```
<form id="rating" action="index.php" method="post">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('rating').submit();">Rating</a>
</form>
```

So if it is clicked I want to use this query:

```
if () {
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `approved` = 1 ORDER BY `rating`");
}
```

Comment: sorry which code? The full form?

Comment: You're not POSTing anything. Create a hidden field and populate with JavaScript then send the form. Otherwise you can use AJAX.

Comment: **AJAX** is what you're looking for

Comment: try my answer, i changed the href to a input type submit so it actually calls that file, maybe you can hide a iframe and do some ajax on the spot really is up to you my answer will get you started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to add an input, like `<input type="hidden" name="hidden_element" value="data"/>` to your form, otherwise there is no POST data for the server to receive.

Then in the `index.php` script you can check if `$_POST['hidden_element']` is set.

For your example:

```
if (isset($_POST['hidden_element']) {
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `approved` = 1 ORDER BY `rating`");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So since your current form doesn't submit any data i like the technique of if multiple buttons are inside a form each should have its propper name and a type of submit 
and on php you check like 
`if (this button was pressed then)
else if (this button was pressed then)
else (redirect in none or what ever you need to do when landed)`

your form, i changed the ahref to an input type submit with the name of button

```
<form id="rating" action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="button"
       onclick="document.getElementById('rating').submit();">Rating
</form>
```

the php action should look like this, you can later implement ajax calling here

```
    if (isset($_POST['button']) === true && empty($_POST['button']) === tre) 
    {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `approved` = 1 ORDER BY `rating`");
    }
```

Comment: When the user clicks on an input of type 'submit' the browsers default response is to submit all input fields in the parent 'form' element to the action URL (with a HTTP GET unless otherwise specified). You don't need to add an onclick event to to emulate this behavior.

Comment: i know this guy had it in his original code so i left it there, im guessing for AJAX reasons @JasonSperske